# Regex taking long time to evaluate

Tags: javascript, regex

At the time of login, I need to allow either username (alphanumeric and some special characters) or email address or username\domain format only. For this purpose, I used this regex with or (`|`) condition. Along with this, I need to allow some other language characters like Japanese, Chinese etc., so included those as well in the same regex. Now, the issue is when I enter characters (>=30) and `@` or some special character, the evaluation of this regex is taking some seconds and browser goes in hang mode.

```
export const usernameRegex = /(^[a-zA-Z0-9._~^#!%+\-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4})+|^[a-zA-Z0-9._~^#!\-]+\\([._-~^#!]|[\p{Ll}\p{Lm}\p{Lt}a-zA-Z0-9-\u3000-\u303f\u3040-\u309f\u30a0-\u30ff\uff00-\uff9f\u4e00-\u9faf\u3400-\u4dbf\u3130-\u318F\uAC00-\uD7AF])+|^([._-~^#!]|[\p{Ll}\p{Lm}\p{Lt}a-zA-Z0-9-\u3000-\u303f\u3040-\u309f\u30a0-\u30ff\uff00-\uff9f\u4e00-\u9faf\u3400-\u4dbf\u3130-\u318F\uAC00-\uD7AF])+$/gu;
```

When I tried removing the other language character set such as `[\p{Ll}\p{Lm}\p{Lt}a-zA-Z0-9-\u3000-\u303f\u3040-\u309f\u30a0-\u30ff\uff00-\uff9f\u4e00-\u9faf\u3400-\u4dbf\u3130-\u318F\uAC00-\uD7AF])+|^([._-~^#!]|[\p{Ll}\p{Lm}\p{Lt}a-zA-Z0-9-\u3000-\u303f\u3040-\u309f\u30a0-\u30ff\uff00-\uff9f\u4e00-\u9faf\u3400-\u4dbf\u3130-\u318F\uAC00-\uD7AF]` it works fine.

I understood that generally regex looks simple but it does a lot under the hood. Is there any modification that needs to be done in this regex, so that it doesn't take time to evaluate. Any help is much appreciated!

**Valid texts:**

```
stackoverflow,
stackoverflow1~,
stackoverflow!#~^-,
stackoverflow@g.co,
stackoverflow!#~^-@g.co,
こんにちは,
你好,
tree\guava
```

**EDIT:**

e.g. Input causing the issue
stackoverflowstackoverflowstackoverflow@

On giving the above text it is taking long time.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7MlE.jpg

Comment: [regex101 tells me it only takes 0.6 ms](https://regex101.com/r/NRmBsh/1) does not match your test input though...

Comment: it is taking time when the text is something like this abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234 and give @ after this text, the examples i gave are to show that kind of texts are valid with comma separated, try this please https://regex101.com/r/D7Uii4/1

Comment: when the input characters are more and then a special character seems to be causing the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex seems to consist of three regular expressions concatenated with `|`

```
(^[a-zA-Z0-9._~^#!%+\-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4})+

^[a-zA-Z0-9._~^#!\-]+\\([._-~^#!]|[\p{Ll}\p{Lm}\p{Lt}a-zA-Z0-9-\u3000-\u303f\u3040-\u309f\u30a0-\u30ff\uff00-\uff9f\u4e00-\u9faf\u3400-\u4dbf\u3130-\u318F\uAC00-\uD7AF])+

^([._-~^#!]|[\p{Ll}\p{Lm}\p{Lt}a-zA-Z0-9-\u3000-\u303f\u3040-\u309f\u30a0-\u30ff\uff00-\uff9f\u4e00-\u9faf\u3400-\u4dbf\u3130-\u318F\uAC00-\uD7AF])+$
```

- first regex `(^...)+` how many times do you think this entire pattern can occur that starts at the beginning of the string. Either it's a second occurence OR it starts at the beginning of the string it can't be both.

  So `^[a-zA-Z0-9._~^#!%+\-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}`
- parts 2 and 3 are mostly identical, only that nr. 2 contains this block `[a-zA-Z0-9._~^#!\-]+\\` followed by what's the rest of the 3rd part.

  So let's combine them: `^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9._~^#!\-]+\\)? ...` and make sure to use non-capturing groups when possible.
- `([abc]|[def])+` can be simplified to `[abcdef]+`. This btw. is the part that's killing your performance.
- your regex ends with a `$`. This was only part of the last part, but I assume you always want to match the entire string? So let's make all 3 (now 2) parts `^ ... $`

Summary:

```js
/^[a-zA-Z0-9._~^#!%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$|^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9._~^#!-]+\\)?[._-~^#!\p{Ll}\p{Lm}\p{Lt}a-zA-Z0-9-\u3000-\u303f\u3040-\u309f\u30a0-\u30ff\uff00-\uff9f\u4e00-\u9faf\u3400-\u4dbf\u3130-\u318F\uAC00-\uD7AF]+$/u
```

---

A JS example how a simple regex would try to match a string, and how it fails, backtracks, retries with the other side of the `|` and so on, and so on.

```js
// let's implement what `/([a-z]|[\p{Ll}])+/u` would do, 
// how it would try to match something.
const a = /[a-z]/; // left part
const b = /[\p{Ll}]/u; // right part

const string = "abc,";

const testNextCharacter = (index) => {
  if (index === string.length) {
    return true;
  }

  const pattern = index + "  ".repeat(index + 1) + "%o.test(%o)";
  const character = string.charAt(index);
  console.log(pattern, a, character);

  // checking the left part && if successful checking the next character
  if (a.test(character) && testNextCharacter(index + 1)) {
    return true;
  }

  // checking the right part && if successful checking the next character
  console.log(pattern, b, character);
  if (b.test(character) && testNextCharacter(index + 1)) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}

console.log("result", testNextCharacter(0));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important}
```

And this are only 4 characters. Why don't you try this with 5,6 characters to get an impression how much work this will be at 20characters.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for your input and answer, I didn't get this statement. ([abc]|[def])+ can be simplified to [abcdef]+. This btw. is the part that's killing your performance. Can you explain on this?

Comment: @sb29595 what exactly do you need explained? How you can combine two positive character groups with an OR in between into a single one? Or why this part is so bad for the performance?

Comment: Does it make difference in performance and how does it affect?

Comment: I've added a snippet that shows you step by step how that construct `([...]|[...])+` tries to match a string (or part of it), how it fails, backtracks, tries again and how many iterations this are at only 4 characters.